# GAN result images are the same during the training process

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a GAN on the MNIST dataset. The code trains right now with mixed results. The issue seems to be the generated images are actually all the same:

[image: GAN Output after 1400 epochs]

You can find my full code below. I tried looking around to see if there was a solution to this and the only thing I found mentioned using `randn` instead of `rand` but I am not using `rand` right now.

```
import os
import sys
from typing import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, callbacks
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Change this to the location of the database directories
DB_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Import databases
sys.path.insert(1, DB_DIR)
from db_utils import get_imdb_dataset, get_speech_dataset, get_single_digit_dataset

def choose_dataset(dataset_type):
    """Select dataset based on string variable."""
    if dataset_type == "nlp":
        return get_imdb_dataset(dir=DB_DIR)
    elif dataset_type == "computer_vision":
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    elif dataset_type == "speech_recognition":
        # (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), (_, _) = get_speech_dataset()
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), (_, _) = get_single_digit_dataset(0)        

    else:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't find dataset.")

    (X_train, X_test) = normalize_dataset(dataset_type, X_train, X_test)

    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = reshape_dataset(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)

def normalize_dataset(string, X_train, X_test):
    """Normalize speech recognition and computer vision datasets."""
    if string == "computer vision":
        X_train = X_train / 255
        X_test = X_test / 255
    else:
        mean = np.mean(X_train)
        std = np.std(X_train)
        X_train = (X_train-std)/mean
        X_test = (X_test-std)/mean

    return (X_train, X_test)

def reshape_dataset(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    """Reshape Computer Vision and Speech datasets."""

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)


class GAN:
    """Generative Adversarial Network for digit generation (MNIST)."""
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(28,28,1), rand_vector_shape=(100,), lr=0.0002, beta=0.5):
        
        # Input sizes
        self.img_shape = input_shape
        self.input_size = rand_vector_shape
        
        # optimizer
        self.opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr, beta)

        # Create Generator model
        self.generator = self.generator_model()
        self.generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = self.opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
        
        # Create Discriminator model
        self.discriminator = self.discriminator_model()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = self.opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
        
        # Set the Discriminator as non trainable in the combined GAN model
        self.discriminator.trainable = False
        
        # Define model input and output
        input = tf.keras.Input(self.input_size)
        generated_img = self.generator(input)
        output = self.discriminator(generated_img)
        
        # Define and compile combined GAN model
        self.GAN = tf.keras.Model(input, output, name="GAN")
        self.GAN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = self.opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

        return None
        
    def discriminator_model(self):
        """Create discriminator model."""
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Discriminator')
        model.add(layers.Flatten())
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

        return model

    def generator_model(self):
        """Create generator model."""
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Generator')
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=np.prod(self.img_shape), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Reshape((28,28)))
        
        return model
    
    def plot_imgs(self, epoch):
        r,c = 4,4

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
        count = 0
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, self.input_size[0]))
                    img = self.generator.predict(noise)[0, :]
                    axs[i,j].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
                    axs[i,j].axis('off')
                    count += 1

        fig.savefig("img/img_epoch_{0}.png".format(epoch))
        plt.title("Epoch " + str(epoch))
        # plt.show()
        return None

    def train(self, X_train, batch_size=128, epochs=2000, save_interval=200):
        half_batch = batch_size//2
        y_pos_train_dis = np.ones((half_batch, 1))
        y_neg_train_dis = np.zeros((half_batch, 1))
        y_train_GAN = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Generate training data for Discriminator

            #   random half_batch amount of real images
            X_pos_train_dis = X_train[np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], half_batch)]
            
            #   random half_batch amount of generated fake images
            X_neg_train_dis = self.generator.predict(np.random.normal(0, 1, (half_batch, self.input_size[0])))

            #   Shuffle and append data using sklearn shuffle function
            # X_train_dis, y_train_dis = tf.concat(shuffle(X_neg_train_dis, X_pos_train_dis, random_state=0), axis=0), tf.concat(shuffle(y_neg_train_dis, y_pos_train_dis, random_state=0), axis=0)
            X_train_dis, y_train_dis = tf.random.shuffle(tf.concat([X_neg_train_dis, X_pos_train_dis], axis=0)), tf.random.shuffle(tf.concat([y_neg_train_dis, y_pos_train_dis], axis=0))

            # Generate training data for combined GAN model
            X_train_GAN = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.input_size[0]))
            
            # Train Discriminator
            loss_dis = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(X_train_dis, y_train_dis)
            
            # Train Generator
            loss_gen = self.GAN.train_on_batch(X_train_GAN, y_train_GAN)

            # Print results
            if epoch%save_interval == 0:
                print("Discriminator loss: {0}, Generator loss: {1}".format(loss_dis[0], loss_gen[0]))
                print("Discriminator acc.: {0}, Generator acc.: {1}".format(loss_dis[1], loss_gen[1]))
                self.plot_imgs(epoch)
                
        return 0

def main():

    gan_model = GAN()
    (X_train, _), (_, _) = choose_dataset("computer_vision")
   
    # Switch from grayscale to (-1,1)
    # X_train = X_train/127.5 - 1.0

    gan_model.train(X_train)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are the accuracies and losses which might give a clue as to the issue:

```
Discriminator loss: 1.0392613410949707, Generator loss: 0.7247573137283325
Discriminator acc.: 0.5078125, Generator acc.: 0.125
Discriminator loss: 0.7155331969261169, Generator loss: 0.7227296829223633
Discriminator acc.: 0.484375, Generator acc.: 0.0
Discriminator loss: 0.7079681158065796, Generator loss: 0.6722699403762817
Discriminator acc.: 0.4609375, Generator acc.: 1.0
Discriminator loss: 0.6883177757263184, Generator loss: 0.7037044763565063
Discriminator acc.: 0.5390625, Generator acc.: 0.0
Discriminator loss: 0.7039847373962402, Generator loss: 0.6718121767044067
Discriminator acc.: 0.453125, Generator acc.: 1.0
Discriminator loss: 0.7004268169403076, Generator loss: 0.6409173607826233
Discriminator acc.: 0.4765625, Generator acc.: 1.0
Discriminator loss: 0.6883779168128967, Generator loss: 0.7788660526275635
Discriminator acc.: 0.5390625, Generator acc.: 0.0
Discriminator loss: 0.6933140754699707, Generator loss: 0.6169038414955139
Discriminator acc.: 0.53125, Generator acc.: 1.0
Discriminator loss: 0.6910691261291504, Generator loss: 0.6194907426834106
Discriminator acc.: 0.5625, Generator acc.: 1.0
Discriminator loss: 0.692711353302002, Generator loss: 0.6367968320846558
Discriminator acc.: 0.5078125, Generator acc.: 1.0
```

Comment: looks like `mode collapse` problem. Read for example here about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/gan-ways-to-improve-gan-performance-acf37f9f59b

Comment: I added the accuracies above. To me, it seems like there is a bug rather than just a lack of convergence on the solution. Do those accuracies above help paint a different picture?

Comment: I tried adding a Wasserstein loss from here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-wasserstein-loss-for-generative-adversarial-networks/ to `self.GAN.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss,...)` and I still get the same result. The images outputted all look the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would get better results if you simply change your activation functions in your models and add a few dropout layers:

```py
def discriminator_model(self):
  """Create discriminator model."""
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Discriminator')
  model.add(layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

  return model

def generator_model(self):
  """Create generator model."""
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Generator')
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='normal'))
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=np.prod(self.img_shape), 
  kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
  model.add(layers.Reshape((28,28)))
        
  return model
```

Also remove the `tf.random.shuffle` as it is making it too difficult for your generator to learn anything plausible:

```py
X_train_dis, y_train_dis = tf.concat([X_neg_train_dis, X_pos_train_dis], axis=0), tf.concat([y_neg_train_dis, y_pos_train_dis], axis=0)
```

The results are ok, but you would be way better off using a CNN network for [image]

**Update**, make sure your discriminator is set to `trainable=False` accordingly:

```py
self.discriminator.trainable = True

loss_dis = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(X_train_dis, y_train_dis)

self.discriminator.trainable = False
            # Train Generator
loss_gen = self.GAN.train_on_batch(X_train_GAN, y_train_GAN)
```

[image]

Here the whole model:

```py
import os
import sys
from typing import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, callbacks
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


def choose_dataset(dataset_type):
    """Select dataset based on string variable."""

    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    (X_train, X_test) = normalize_dataset(dataset_type, X_train, X_test)

    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = reshape_dataset(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)

def normalize_dataset(string, X_train, X_test):
    """Normalize speech recognition and computer vision datasets."""
    if string == "computer vision":
        X_train = X_train / 255
        X_test = X_test / 255
    else:
        mean = np.mean(X_train)
        std = np.std(X_train)
        X_train = (X_train-std)/mean
        X_test = (X_test-std)/mean

    return (X_train, X_test)

def reshape_dataset(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    """Reshape Computer Vision and Speech datasets."""

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)


class GAN:
    """Generative Adversarial Network for digit generation (MNIST)."""
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(28,28,1), rand_vector_shape=(100,), lr=0.0002, beta=0.5):
        
        # Input sizes
        self.img_shape = input_shape
        self.input_size = rand_vector_shape
        
        # optimizer
        self.opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr, beta)

        # Create Generator model
        self.generator = self.generator_model()
        self.generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = self.opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
        
        # Create Discriminator model
        self.discriminator = self.discriminator_model()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001, beta), metrics = ['accuracy'])
        
        # Set the Discriminator as non trainable in the combined GAN model
        self.discriminator.trainable = False
        
        # Define model input and output
        input = tf.keras.Input(self.input_size)
        generated_img = self.generator(input)
        output = self.discriminator(generated_img)
        
        # Define and compile combined GAN model
        self.GAN = tf.keras.Model(input, output, name="GAN")
        self.GAN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = self.opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

        return None
        
    def discriminator_model(self):
        """Create discriminator model."""
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Discriminator')
        model.add(layers.Flatten())
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

        return model

    def generator_model(self):
        """Create generator model."""
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='Generator')
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=np.prod(self.img_shape), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
        model.add(layers.Reshape((28,28)))
        
        return model
    
    def plot_imgs(self, epoch):
        seed = tf.random.normal((16, 100))
        predictions = self.generator(seed, training=False)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
        for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
            plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
            plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
            plt.axis('off')

        fig.savefig("img/img_epoch_{0}.png".format(epoch))
        plt.title("Epoch " + str(epoch))
        # plt.show()
        return None

    def train(self, X_train, batch_size=128, epochs=4000, save_interval=200):
        half_batch = batch_size//2
        y_pos_train_dis = tf.ones((half_batch, 1))
        y_neg_train_dis = tf.zeros((half_batch, 1))
        y_train_GAN = tf.ones((batch_size, 1))

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Generate training data for Discriminator

            #   random half_batch amount of real images
            X_pos_train_dis = X_train[np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], half_batch)]
            
            #   random half_batch amount of generated fake images
            X_neg_train_dis = self.generator.predict(tf.random.normal((half_batch, self.input_size[0])))

            #   Shuffle and append data using sklearn shuffle function
            # X_train_dis, y_train_dis = tf.concat(shuffle(X_neg_train_dis, X_pos_train_dis, random_state=0), axis=0), tf.concat(shuffle(y_neg_train_dis, y_pos_train_dis, random_state=0), axis=0)
            X_train_dis, y_train_dis = tf.concat([X_neg_train_dis, X_pos_train_dis], axis=0), tf.concat([y_neg_train_dis, y_pos_train_dis], axis=0)

            # Generate training data for combined GAN model
            X_train_GAN = tf.random.normal((batch_size, self.input_size[0]))
            
            # Train Discriminator
            self.discriminator.trainable = True

            loss_dis = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(X_train_dis, y_train_dis)

            self.discriminator.trainable = False
            # Train Generator
            loss_gen = self.GAN.train_on_batch(X_train_GAN, y_train_GAN)

            # Print results
            if epoch%save_interval == 0:
                print("Discriminator loss: {0}, Generator loss: {1}".format(loss_dis[0], loss_gen[0]))
                print("Discriminator acc.: {0}, Generator acc.: {1}".format(loss_dis[1], loss_gen[1]))
                self.plot_imgs(epoch)
                
        return 0


gan_model = GAN()
(X_train, _), (_, _) = choose_dataset("computer_vision")

gan_model.train(X_train)
```

Comment: Isn’t the issue still there to some extent? Why is it plotting the same image over and over ^ it should be different images to my understanding

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Very odd, I made the changed with the exception of the changing the model itself (I want to try Dense and then work up to more complicated layers) but I don't get this same result. Mine looks a lot worse